Isomorphism between deck transformations and permutations onto the fiber
I came across this problem in Fulton's Algebraic topology textbook (problem 11.39) and I can't seem to get to the bottom of it. The problem is as follows:
Let $p:Y\to X$ be a covering, with $Y$ connected and $X$ path-connected. Let $x\in X$, and set $S=p^{-1}(x)$. Any automorphism of the covering restricts to a permutation of $S$, and the automorphism is determined by this restriction, so Aut$(Y/X)\subset$ Aut$(S)$. Show that Aut$(Y/X)\simeq \{\varphi\in\text{Aut}(S): \varphi(z*\sigma)=\varphi(z)*\sigma\;$ for all $z\in S$ and all closed paths $\sigma$ at $x\}$
To be clear with the notation, Fulton defines $y*\gamma$ to be the ending point of the lifted path $\tilde{\gamma}$ with starting point at $y$ ($y*\gamma=\tilde{\gamma}_y(1)$)
I managed to show that Aut$(Y/X)\subset$ Aut$(S)$ and one inclusion (Aut$(Y/X)\subseteq \{\varphi\in\text{Aut}(S): [...]\}$) but I'm not being able to show the other inclusion. Does anyone have a clue on how to approach the problem?

Fix $y\in p^{-1}(x)$. If $Z$ is path connected and locally path connected, $f\colon Z\to X$ a map and $z\in Z$ such that $f(z) = x$, then there is a lift $F\colon Z\to Y$ of $f$ with $F(z)=y$ iff $f_\ast(\pi_1(Z,z))\subset p_\ast(\pi_1(Y,y))$. If one of these conditions is true, $F(z')$ is defined as follows. Take any path $\alpha$ from $z$ to $z'$ and lift the path $f\circ \alpha$ in $X$ to the path $\beta$ in $Y$ starting at $y$ and put $F(z')=\beta(1)$.
In the case at hand let $y\in S=p^{-1}(x)$ and suppose $\varphi\in \mathrm{Aut}(S)$ satisfies the condition of the question. If we know that $p_\ast(\pi_1(Y,y)) = p_\ast(\pi_1(Y,\varphi(y))$ we get a map $f\colon Y\to Y$ that lifts $p\colon Y\to X$ with the property that $f(y)=\varphi(y)$, that is it is an automorphism of coverings. I leave it to you to check that in this case the restriction of $f$ to $S$ is equal to $\varphi$.
To see that $p_\ast(\pi_1(Y,y)) = p_\ast(\pi_1(Y,\varphi(y))$, let $\alpha\in \pi_1(Y,y)$ and $\beta$ a lift of $p_\ast(\alpha)$ starting at $\varphi(y)$. Then by definition $$\beta(1) = \varphi(y)\ast p_\ast(\alpha) = \varphi(y\ast p_\ast(\alpha)) = \varphi(\alpha(1)) = \varphi(y),$$
which means that $\beta\in \pi_1(Y,\varphi(y))$ and by assumption $p_\ast(\beta) = p_\ast(\alpha)$, hence $p_\ast(\pi_1(Y,y)) \subset p_\ast(\pi_1(Y,\varphi(y))$ and the reverse inclusion is completely analogous.

The lifting criterion $f_\ast(\pi_1(Z,z))\subset p_\ast(\pi_1(Y,y))$ only applies for locally path-connected spaces.

@PaulFrost This is correct. I think you have to assume the base is locally path connected, since otherwise the fundamental group might not act transitively on the coverings. I don't have a copy of Fulton's book, therefore I don't know if this is implicitly assumed.

No, he does not make this assumption. By the way, the problem occurs at the end of the chapter "Covering spaces". The fundamental group is introduced in the following chapter.

I am not surprised that you were not able to show the other inclusion. Under the given conditons "$Y$ connected and $X$ path-connected" it is in general not true. See Vincent Boelens's answer for a proof under stronger assumptions.
Here is a counterexample. Let $T \subset \mathbb R^2$ denote the closed topologist's sine curve $T = L \cup S$ with $L = \{0\} \times [-1,1]$ and $S= \{\left(x, \sin(\frac \pi x)\right) \mid x \in (0,1] \}$. Let $\tau_n  : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ denote the translation by the vector $(0,n)$ with $n \in \mathbb Z$. Define $T_n = \tau_n(T)$. We have $T_n \cap T_{n+1} = \{(n+1,0)\}$ and $T_n \cap T_m =\emptyset$ if $m \ge n+2$. Now define
$$Y = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} T_n .$$
$Y$ is an infinite chain of copies of $T$. It is well known that $T$ is connected and has two path-components ($L$ and $S$) which are contractible. Hence $Y$ is connected and has infinitely many path components $P_n = \tau_n(S) \cup \{n+1\} \times [-1,1]$ which are contractible.
The additive group $\mathbb Z$ operates on $Y$ via the translations $\tau_n$ (which restrict to homeomorphisms on $Y$).
The quotient $X = Y /\mathbb Z$ of this operation is nothing else than the quotient space $T/E$ obtained by identifying $E= \{ (0,0), (0,1)\}$ to a single point. The quotient map $p : Y \to X$ is a covering map. This is completely analogous to the standard covering map $p : \mathbb R \to [0,1]/\{0,1\} = S^1$.
The space $X = T/E$ is a variant of the Warsaw circle:

It is well-known that this space is path-connected and simply connected (it has no non-contractible loops).
Pick any $x \in X$. Then $S =p^{-1}(x)$ is countably infinite. Since $X$ is simply connected, lifts of closed paths are again closed paths. Thus $z * \sigma = z$ for all $z \in S$ so that the condition $\varphi(z*\sigma)=\varphi(z)*\sigma$ is satisfied for all $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(S)$.
However, the only deck transformtions of $Y$ are the translations $\tau_n$. This shows that $\operatorname{Aut}(Y/X) \subsetneqq \operatorname{Aut}(S)$.
